# Invalid subplatform for platform

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

Hello any one please correct me about this error ,
While adding new device and updating my provisioning profile getting this error since last few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, and the only workaround which I found so far is to **delete** and **create** profile again.